# Joining based on case condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables **TableA** and **TableB**. The key to join these two table is **ID**

TableA

| ID | code | code_T |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 100 |
| 2 | 101 | 290 |
| 3 | 102 | 300 |

TableB

| Id | Name | Desc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | ABC |
| 2 | A | ABC |
| 2 | B | CDE |

What I am looking forward is to handle the duplicating IDs from TableB to avoid cartesian product by limiting the joining by below condition

**1. If TableA.code_T = 290 then join only with the row from TableB where TableB.Name = A and return TableB.Desc

2. If TableA.code_T = 300 then join only with the row from TableB where TableB.Name = B and return TableB.Desc**

Comment: Why do you combine 290 with A? Why not with B? What if the value is not 290, but 190 or 590? Will that have an impact? And why do you want to join ID 3 with one of the IDs 2? I don't see how the rows are related. What is your rule precisely to identify which rows to join?

Comment: 290 is a static value which defines the 'A' is the Name for ID 2 in tableB. Similarly 300 is the static value which represnts the name B. The IDs are same but with different Name

Comment: Hm, I still don't get it. If code_t not in (290,300), then join with all rows with the same ID? If code_t = 290, then join with all rows with the same ID and Name = 'A'? If code_t = 300, then join with all rows where Name = 'B', regardless of the ID? Does that make sense? It seems a weird set of rules.

Comment: Logical implication `a->b` is expressed as `not a or b`. So your ON condition can be `on a.id=b.id and (a.code_T != 290 or b.Name ='A') and (a.code_T != 300 or b.Name ='B')`

Answer (score 1):

According to the description, you need this condition to join:

```
select a.id, a.code, a.code_T, b.description 
from tablea a join tableb b
on a.id = b.id and (a.code_t, b.name) in ((290, 'A'), ('300', 'B'))
```

or equivalent:

```
select a.id, a.code, a.code_T, b.description
from tablea a join tableb b
on a.id = b.id and (   (a.code_t = 290 and b.name = 'A') 
                    or (a.code_t = 300 and b.name = 'B') )
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GODfbwl8)

This way all rows which have code_T other than 290 or 300 will be ignored.